# Not able to process cross domain json request in Google app engine and get response in json

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, google-app-engine

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://XXXXXXXX.com/getProduct.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

My Client side jsp Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery.js"></script>

<script>
function submitLogin() {
        var obj = {
                "productMasterId" : "1"
        };

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "http://XXXXXXXX.com/getProduct.html", 
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'text/javascript; charset=utf-8',
            crossDomain : true,
            mimeType: 'text/javascript',
            success : function(response) {
                alert("done");
                alert(response);
            }
            ,
            error : function(response) {

            }
        }); 

    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:submitLogin()">click </a>
```

My server side code :

```
@RequestMapping("/getProductDetailsForReview.html")
    public @ResponseBody PaymentForm getProductDetailsForReview(@RequestBody PaymentForm paymentForm, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.debug("Start of method getProductDetailsForReview");
        PaymentForm form = userPaymentService.getProductForReview(paymentForm);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        log.debug("End of method getProductDetailsForReview");
        return form;
    }
```

CORS Filter :

```
package com.bullbeardevice.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class SimpleCORSFilter
 */
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("In CORS Filter");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

response :

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8888
Request URL:http://localhost:8888/getProductDetailsForReview.html
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:23
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8888
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/samplekit/jsp/index.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
{"productMasterId":"1"}:
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:application/javascript
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cache-Control:no-store
Content-Length:83
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Wed, 15 Oct 2014 07:09:48 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Development/1.0
```

Spring xml Config :

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bull.*" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.gmr.web.multipart.GMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver2"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <property name="basename" value="ApplicationResources" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven
        content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="ApplicationResources" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: If I am using CORS and defining a filter and set reponse header as response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") then I am getting GET http://localhost:8888/getProductDetailsForReview.html 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: My request is reaching filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was just that I was using @RequestBody in the arguments of the method in my controller. Now I have replaced that with the @requestparam it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's some info missing I would say, but to try to help. Few things could be wrong. Starting from the most obvious

Your request is targeting "http://XXXXXXXX.com/getProduct.html", but your mapping is "/getProductDetailsForReview.html", but I'll presume that this a typo. The problem that you mentioned in your comment is most likely due to wrong contentTypes in the response.

Providing that you're using CORS filter as e.g. suggested in the accepted answer [CORS Filter not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846309/cors-filter-not-working-as-intended). The following will work

```
<script>
    function submitLogin() {
        var obj = {
            "productMasterId": "1"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://XXXXXXXX.com/getProductDetailsForReview",
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("done");
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:submitLogin()">click </a>
```

Notice that I've removed the contentType and that I've removed the html from the request. The reason is that if html is present the contentType of the response will be set to text/html, different than the one you set in the request

```
@RequestMapping("/getProductDetailsForReview")
    public @ResponseBody PaymentForm getProductDetailsForReview(@RequestBody PaymentForm paymentForm, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.debug("Start of method getProductDetailsForReview");
        PaymentForm form = userPaymentService.getProductForReview(paymentForm);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        log.debug("End of method getProductDetailsForReview");
        return form;
    }
```

Combine the three, the proper CORS filter, slightly modified Ajax call, and the modified server mapping and you'll have it working properly, 
best

---

to reflect on your comment in an update. Spring MVC uses content negotiation to reason what should be the response content type, and the suffix takes precedence over other options. I think that that is your issue, take a look at

http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

this being said, try adding the *favorPathExtension = "false"*  property to your Spring MVC configuration,

```
 <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
...
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
...
</bean>
```

let me know how did it workout

Comment: I cannot remove html from my action /getProductDetailsForReview because I have given *.html in my dispatcher servlet url-pattern in web.xml. I have also updated my question with CORS filter.

Comment: I have updated my question with the request and response header I am able to see in the browser. Please check. I can figure it out that the in the response header I am getting content-type as text/html and I am expecting json. May be thats the issue. Please suggest

Comment: that is exactly the issue, and most likely for the reason mentioned, can you paste the XML of your spring mvc configuration

Comment: I have come across to a link i.e. http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ will it work for GAE also. I have edited my question.

Comment: By everything you wrote, CORS is already working for you. Check the headers you posted, the request accepts application/json, but the response gives, text/html that's why you get the 415 Unsupported Media Type.
The reason why you get this contentType in the response is 'casue your request has .html as a suffix, so Spring MVC deduces that the response type should be text/html. Set the <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" /> in your contentNegotionManager bean, and I'll bet you that the things will start working :)

Comment: Bt in filter I am setting the content type as application/json still it is not reflecting. My request is reaching the filter bt it is not processed by controller

Comment: Okay I'll do it just now then will come back to you. Thanks by the way.

Comment: When I am adding <mvc:annotation-driven  content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/> in my xml it is showing me error. cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'content-negotiation-manager' is not allowed to appear in element 'mvc:annotation-
 driven'.

Comment: you've probably duplicate it, paste your complete configuration, and I'll help

Comment: The configuration changed in Spring MVC 3.2, but try just adding

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    </bean> , let me know if it worked

Comment: Not working class not found for  org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean

Comment: you've probably kept the previous changes in xml. You should revert your xml to how it was yesterday and just add 

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver"> <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" /> </bean>

Comment: I never added this bean in my xml.

Comment: I thing you have 'cause I see it in your pasted configuration. It was on my suggestion, but it works only from 3.2 and up

Comment: Thanks @Master Slave for your help but I have solved the issue. It was just the requestBody annotation that I am using. I hv replaced it with requestparam now it is working fine :-)