# How to resolve CORS error in alfresco webscripts in alfresco sdk?

Tags: java, angular, cors, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have created a alfresco webscript which can be accessed using thus url :

http://localhost:9191/alfresco/s/search/item/{itemIid}
e.g. : 
http://localhost:9191/alfresco/s/search/item/it0001

when i hit directly from the browser address bar it work perfectly but when i invoke this from my angular service then i am getting CORS error

Failed to load http://localhost:9191/alfresco/s/search/item/it0001: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4201' is therefore not allowed access.

My angular part is this :

```
convert1(itemId:string){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type','*');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    headers.append('Authorization','Basic zfsdfsdfsdfdsf=');    
    return  this.http.get(http://localhost:9191/alfresco/s/search/item/it0001,{headers:headers});   
}
```

In alfresco-repo side I have addedd following in webscript code but this has not helped.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

what changes i can do in my alfresco-repo amp plugin so that this error can be avoided.

Any insight would be highly appreciated.

--------After Jeff Potts answer-----

```
1. D:\abcd-app-repo\target\amp-war\WEB-INF\web.xml
<!-- CORS Filter Begin -->
  <filter>
      <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
         <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
         <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
         <param-value>origin, authorization, x-file-size, x-file-name, content-type, accept, x-file-type</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
         <param-value>3600</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </filter>
   <!-- CORS Filter End -->

   <!-- Enterprise filter placeholder -->

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Global Localization Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping>

   <!-- CORS Filter Mappings Begin -->
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/s/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/cmisbrowser/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <!-- CORS Filter Mappings End -->
```

2. In alfresco/WEB-INF/lib added cors-filter-2.5.jar, java-property-utils-1.9.1.jar Or   cors-filter-2.4.jar and java-property-utils-1.9.1.jar Or cors-filter-1.9.3.jar but it does not work for me.

Comment: probably the problem is on back-end.. do you use webapi in aspnet?

Comment: Thanks puntanet, i guess you are right, i have problem in my back end code. But i am using java based alfresco webscripts

Comment: i had a similar problem but in aspnet..I solved by adding EnableCors in my back.. you can try looking for something like this for java

Comment: Thanks a lot puntanet. Can i know that you were developing alfresco plugin or other web app . . .

Comment: I development web app for company management

Comment: try adding all the headers in your webscript `response`. refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846309/cors-filter-not-working-as-intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Go into your expanded alfresco webapp directory under WEB-INF and edit web.xml.
2. Do a search for "CORS Filter".
3. Uncomment out the filter.
4. Now restart Tomcat and try again.

Comment: Let's back up. You're doing a GET which should not have a problem hitting the endpoint if it is functioning correctly and your ports are open, etc. Can you use curl to do the same GET and see what happens? Maybe use curl -v to turn on verbose logging.